# c# - ThreadAbortException rethrowing

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadabortexception

MSDN says, for the `Thread.Abort` method-

> When this method is invoked on a thread, the system throws a ThreadAbortException in the thread to abort it. ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught by application code, but is re-thrown at the end of the catch block unless ResetAbort is called. ResetAbort cancels the request to abort, and prevents the ThreadAbortException from terminating the thread. Unexecuted finally blocks are executed before the thread is aborted.

So the exception would be thrown only once from the most immediate `catch` block, or from all encapsulating `catch` blocks ?
Also, when saying unexecuted `finally` blocks are executed, does it include both totally unexecuted and partially executed blocks?

Comment: why don't you write a piece of code and try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finally` blocks are always fully protected from `ThreadAbortException` both if they are executing and if they would need to be executed during the rollback of the stack.

And yes, clearly the `ThreadAbortException` will be automatically re-raised at the end of any `try... catch` block in the same thread that intercepts it, otherwise it would be meaningless. What use would it have to have a `ThreadAbortException` with only two "lives"?

Would it be logical that this could stop a `ThreadAbortException`?

```
try
{
    try
    {
        // The Thread.Abort "happens" here
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
catch 
{
}
```

while this wouldn't?

```
try
{
    // The Thread.Abort "happens" here
    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
}
catch
{
}
```